# Relationship between estimates in 2 linear models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, linear-model

I am considering two linear models with model matrices related as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\text{Model} \ 1 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\vdots \\
\mu_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
1 & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_{n2} & x_{n3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\text{Model} \ 2 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\vdots \\
\mu_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & cx_{12} + x_{13} & x_{13} \\
1 & cx_{22} + x_{23}& x_{23} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & cx_{n2} + x_{n3} & x_{n3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta^*_0 \\
\beta^*_1 \\
\beta^*_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\end{equation*}

$$y\sim N(\mu,I_n \sigma^2)$$

Under what conditions is $\frac{\hat\beta_1}{\hat\sigma_{\beta_1}} = \frac{\hat\beta^*_1}{\hat\sigma_{\beta^*_1}}$, and how can it be proven?